# What content does the paid Magic 2014 version have that the free version doesn't?

Tags: mtg-duels-of-the-planeswalkers

I just downloaded [Magic 2014](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.stainlessgames.D14) on my Android device as a free app. Unfortunately, when you launch it you're asked you if you want to purchase the full game for $10.

My question is:

**What is the missing content for the full version?**

Comment: Are you asking the difference between the full and the free version? or what content resides on the android device when you download the free version that isn't used until you pay for the full version?

Comment: @Brian I'm going to charitably assume that it's the first possible question, since the second is only useful if someone wants to pirate the game and that's not the kind of question we are legally able to help with. I've edited the question accordingly.

Answer (score 3):

With the free version you can do the tutorial and then the Innistrad plane. The other planes are locked. You can also build a deck from a few booster packs, 5 or 6 if I remember right, and "test" it against an AI deck that does nothing but summon 1/1 fliers over and over.

The [Innistrad](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Innistrad) plane consists of 5 battles which you can do repeatedly to unlock the 30 extra cards for each deck.  You start with a green deck, unlock a red one in the tutorial, and a white one on Innistrad.

For anything beyond that you have to buy the game. I had intended to do that, but now it says my Nexus 4 is not compatible, so unless your android device is a full on tablet, forget about it.

Answer (score 0):

New areas of the game and I believe 2 new battle tactics. Since I downloaded the full game I'm not sure that this is all of the content.